# Variance Swap Vega

Tags: swaps, vega

I am currently reading the paper of Derman and al for my master thesis on Variance Swap.
At one point one says that "The variance vega is largest when the option is ATM", considering here a call option on a stock.

I must say, I am having some difficulties to understand that. The only reason I came up with is that vanilla option are almost linear in volatility at ATM.

Edit:

In order to clarify my questions which is not clearly explicit.

[image]

Comment: What is the option? How is it related to a variance swap?

Comment: Sorry I just edited my post: a call option on a stock and the variance exposure is highest when the call is ATM

Comment: What do you mean "Variance vega"? Should it be option vega?

Comment: It is basically the same apparently yes, except the notation here is dC/ variance

Comment: So then it is not the same. Rather "Variance Vega" is $\nu/(2\sigma)$ where $\nu$ is the usual (volatility) Vega.

Comment: Exactly, so my understanding is since vega is always positive in the BSM, the model is a monotonic function of volatility. Therefore, variance vega is at the largest at ATM option

Comment: I don't understand what you say... what "model"?. It would help if you could add a link to the paper. Or a screenshot of the page you are referring to. Also this seems to have nothing to do with variance swaps so please edit the question details.

Comment: The formula for Vega of a vanilla call or put https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks has a max for $F=S e^{-rT}=K$

Comment: Do you also assume constant volatility?